# jQuery prepend is appending

Tags: jquery, ajax

My HTML layout is as such

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-5" id="container">

</ul>
```

The dynamic creation of `<li><img src="image here"></li>` is done using

```
$("<li/>").prepend('<img src="'+img+'" />').appendTo('#container');
```

Although it's appending to the end of the last added image, instead of the start, the reason I want this is so I don't have to keep scrolling down

Comment: Are you trying to add the new element as the first element in the `container`?

Comment: @J0HN, yes that's correct

Comment: It's currently adding them all one after another, everything is working fine, I just want them to prepend before the last added image instead of after

Comment: I think it should be `$("<li/>").append('<img src="'+img+'" />').prependTo('#container');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to prepend it to the new container, instead of appending it.

```
$("<li/>").append('<img src="'+img +'" />').prependTo('#container');
```

I had to make some changes to get the fiddle work without the image, but I believe you understand where I'm heading.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zr5X3/)